# Mongo : drop collection on v4.4 exception

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my mongo is a single replica set db

i have version 4.4 compatibility feature on, and event though the drop function on jvm driver receives a ClientSession, it throws this exception when i try dropping it inside a transaction:

> Unable to read from a snapshot due to pending collection catalog
> changes; please retry the operation

also when i change write concern to majority and read concern to snapshot, i get this exception:

> Command failed with error 263 (OperationNotSupportedInTransaction):
> 'Cannot run 'drop' in a multi-document transaction

is there any way i could drop collection inside transaction and if not what is the use in having ClientSession argument in drop function at all?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Collections cannot presently be dropped in transactions. This is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Multi-document-Transactions).

> what is the use in having ClientSession argument in drop function at all?!?!

Sessions are used for other purposes besides transactions, for example to kill operations across a sharded cluster.